# Active button always active in each division

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my sample form HTML code. In further, I need when click the button in each section the button stays active and it shows red color background. on the other hand, inactive buttons change the grey background color. For example when we click the "print foil thickness" label button 3 then it will active
button 3 and remains 4,5,6,7,8, Best Fit buttons are disabled.

```html
<form id="msform">  
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-card">
      <label class="label-order">Order Set Required:</label>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Kit">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Replacement Set</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Complete Set</button>
      </div>
      <label class="label-order">Print Foil Thickness:</label>
      <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">7</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Best Fit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="label-order">Print Foil Opening (in mils):</label>
      <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">7</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Best Fit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="label-order">Sphere Diameter To Be Used (in mils):</label>
      <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">7</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Best Fit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry it is difficult but please explain again what you want without mixing both scenarios. Also your `<div>` aren't closed properly. Add one more `</div>` before `</fieldset>`

Comment: I believe what you want is use ratio input instead of buttons.
You still can make the ratio input look like an button, active/disable.
The reason Why I am sugesting the ratio it's because you're going to retrieve the data from your form.

Comment: @DanDrix8391 okay thx for your suggestion i ll use radio button for this instead of using normal buttons